# How to make a button in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to make a Save button for each post in facebook(This has my own extension functionality).Have to place this in facebook just similar to Like,Share,Comment how i can achieve this?.

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: In FacebookPage we Have Like,Comment and Share,I need include another Link like that "Save".So facebook page should have Like,Comment,Share and Save.Is this possible?.

Answer (score 0):

The Like button is a simple plugin that lets people quickly share content on Facebook.

Clicking a Like button on a site creates a connection in the graph between the content and the person who clicks the button. Clicking the Like button also publishes an Open Graph Like action, and displays stories on that person's timeline and their friends' news feeds. This story will link back to the site and drive distribution of content.

The story created by the Like action can be enriched by using meta tags to turn a simple HTML page into an Open Graph object. If you plan to use the Like button on any page on your website, you should follow the guide to including meta tags to ensure published stories look great in timeline and news feed and get the best possible distribution. Also read our best practices document on maximizing distribution for hints on how to improve interactions between your content and Facebook.

The Like button itself displays a count of all the likes and shares of the content and a few other metrics listed in the Frequently Asked Questions, below. An option to comment on the story appears when the Like button is clicked, if it is configured correctly. If someone comments after clicking Like, that gives the published story prominence in news feed.

You can use the configurator below to customize the layout and style of Like buttons and implement the plugin in minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I need a save button which invoke my extension of the browser.how i can achieve this?.